# iPhone/Android - securing images downloaded by app

Tags: iphone, android, security, image, storage

I know there are a lot of posts about storing images on disk, both for Android and iPhone. What I would like to know is how to hide these files from user (disable access from both device itself and PC sd-card reader).

I want my app to download copyrighted images that should be only accessed using my application.

- Android & iPhone,
- multiple images (I'm guessing around 50-200, maybe more)
- image size +/- 150-300 KB, various size but less than 1000x1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt the downloaded bytes and then save it with any of your own format file extension. Then save it on your disk. While Reading Decrypt the data and use it accordingly.

This the only way i think to implement this. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Check this link for file encryption http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesFile.html .  there are many on the net search for your own requirement

Comment: Can I use some server side code like PHP to encrypt files (AES 128 enough?) and decrypt both without problems on Android and iPhone?

Comment: Yes you can . in fact it will lessen the load on your app. 
Your app just need to decrypt it

Answer (score 1):

SD cards are FAT formatted, i.e. all content is available to all. Your only real option is encryption. You can probably adapt the code here to encrypt and decrypt a file: http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/39/

Obviously you'd have your app generate a random key on first run, and store it in your preferences (which is private to your app on internal storage).